# How to validate data encoded with formData

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, form-data

I'm using the vue with laravel.
In vue I have a customer registration form. In the form there is data (name, address) and photo of the client.

I pack everything inside a formData object to send the image and data to the server.

**My vue:**

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", this.data.logo);

formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(this.data));

axios.post(`urlServer`, formData).then(response => {

...

}).catch((error) =>{ });
```

**in my laravel**

```
public function update(Request $request){

   $array =  $request->all();

   $request->validate([ //not working
      'name' => 'required'
   ]);


}
```

How do I validate the data? The data is encode in my laravel. In my service I have them using json_decode ($ array ['data'], true);

In my controller I want to use something like:

```
$request->validate...
```

Does anyone know how to create a validation?

Comment: could you show me what did you get in `$array` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Request does not have a `validate` function.

One way to validate your request is:

```
<?php

...

use Validator;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    ...
    public function update(Request $request){

        $array =  $request->all();
        $rules = array(
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'address' => 'required|strgin',
            'photo' => 'image'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($array, $ules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->setStatusCode(400)->respond([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => $validator->messages(),
                    'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
                ]
            ]);
        }
        ...
        // store your data...
     }
}
```

Also check the available [validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#available-validation-rules)